# Asterisk Agi programming With C#?

Tags: c#, .net, asterisk, telephony, agi

I want to work with Asterisk and develop some Programs for working with that.
 So I found [AGI](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+AGI).

> And for **first questions**: Is there any *sample, good tutorial and tips* for use that.

and  I want to know Is it possible to **`developing program's with AGI to work on these Issues:`**

> - Dial-plan Creator
> - Channel Manager
> - SoftPhone with **AGI**, Instead of **RTC** or etc (*I wrote SoftPhone which is developed by C# based on RTC communication*).

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by SoftPhone with AGI, not SIP or H232.  AGI and the AMI are just methods of controlling Asterisk's behavior.  They are not going to allow you to create a soft phone that doesn't use protocols that are already implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is tons of info on the [voip-info.org wiki](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+manager+Example%3a+C+Sharp/). For what you want to do you mostly need the AMI (Asterisk Manager Interface) and not AGI.

Comment: anything about AMI? (Code sample or Useful Link)